# TradingView PineScript. How to set label size to a smaller size than size.tiny?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am writing an indicator script in PineScript for TradingView where I need to plot dots (or any other shape) in the future (so to the right of the last candle).

I managed to do that by drawing a circle shape using the `label.new` statement.
My problem is that the shape is too large. I am using `size=size.tiny`, but the shape is still too large.
Is there a way to make the size of the shape smaller than `size.tiny`?
Specifying the size by a number would be ideal.

This code snippet shows what I am using now:

```
if barstate.islast
    ExpDate1 = "2023-02-17" 
    EMPrice1 = 366.46
 
    timeEM1  = timestamp(ExpDate1)
    label.new(x=timeEM1 , y=EMPrice1, xloc=xloc.bar_time,color=color.blue, size=size.tiny, style=label.style_circle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience `size.auto` is often smaller then `size.tiny`.

Its worth a try.

Comment: I am using size.auto now. It seems indeed to be the best option! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no smaller size than `size.tiny`.

As a workaround, you can actually pass `●` as your label's `text` argument and not worry about its style. That will show up smaller than `label.style_circle`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index + 10, high, "●", color=color.new(color.white, 100), textcolor=color.green)
    label.new(bar_index + 20, high, "", style=label.style_circle, color=color.red, size=size.tiny)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Good idea!
The only thing is that there is an offset in the Y-coordinate.
The dot character is plotted a little too high. You can see it in your screenshot.
I could compensate this y-offset by subtracting the offset from the y-coordinate, but that offset is probably different with every ticker. Or maybe not. I should try and see.

Comment: It seems that the Y-offset is proportional to the zoom level of the chart. So a constant offset does not solve the problem.
But apparantly no other solution exist.